# Dart flutter make an array based on similar type of id

Tags: flutter, dart

I getting a json data array like this.

```
  final info = [
  {
    "id": "cart1",
    "product": {"id": "01"},
    "seller": {
      "id": "seller1",
    },
    "quantity": 8,
    "amount": 2544,
  },
  {
    "id": "cart2",
    "product": {"id": "02"},
    "seller": {
      "id": "seller1",
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "amount": 318,
  },
  {
    "id": "cart3",
    "product": {"id": "03"},
    "seller": {
      "id": "seller2",
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "amount": 200,
  },
];
```

So I have a list of array like info. Where I have to format that like result so that I can show data ui. I have no Idea how can I that? I am new in flutter please help me .

```
final result = [
  {
    "seller": "seller1",
    "products": [
      {"productId": "01", "quantity": 8, "amount": 2544},
      {"productId": "02", "quantity": 1, "amount": 318},
    ],
    "price": 2862
  },
  {
    "seller": "seller2",
    "products": [
      {"productId": "03", "quantity": 1, "amount": 200},
    ],
    "price": 200
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a class having methods to order the data as you want. Just call the method `_orderData()` from this class:

```
class Test {
  final info = [
    {
      "id": "cart1",
      "product": {"id": "01"},
      "seller": {
        "id": "seller1",
      },
      "quantity": 8,
      "amount": 2544,
    },
    {
      "id": "cart2",
      "product": {"id": "02"},
      "seller": {
        "id": "seller1",
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "amount": 318,
    },
    {
      "id": "cart3",
      "product": {"id": "03"},
      "seller": {
        "id": "seller2",
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "amount": 200,
    },
  ];


  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _orderData() {
    Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _map = {};
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> _list = [];
    for (Map<String, dynamic> item in info) {
      String _key = item['seller']['id'];
      if (!_map.containsKey(_key)) {
        _map[_key] = [_getFormattedMap(item)];
      } else {
        _map[_key]?.add(_getFormattedMap(item));
      }
    }
    _map.entries.forEach((element) {
      _list.add(_getFormattedMap2(element));
    });
    print(_list);
    return _list;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _getFormattedMap(Map<String, dynamic> item) {
    return {
      'productId': item['product']['id'],
      'quantity': item['quantity'],
      'amount': item['amount'],
    };
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _getFormattedMap2(
      MapEntry<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>> entry) {
    return {
      'seller': entry.key,
      'products': entry.value,
      'price': _getTotal(entry),
    };
  }

  num _getTotal(MapEntry<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>> entry) {
    num total = 0;
    entry.value.forEach((element) {
      total += element['amount'];
    });
    return total;
  }
}
```